# Dynamic text boxes generation

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make my text boxes dynamic, currently I have 4 text boxes added manually but want to add more 4 boxes in each row when I click on Add row button

```js
function insertRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("createTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
  
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var t1 = document.createElement("input");
  t1.id = "SERIAL1" + index;
  cell1.appendChild(t1);
  
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var t2 = document.createElement("input");
  t2.id = "SERIAL2" + index;
  cell2.appendChild(t2);
  
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var t3 = document.createElement("input");
  t3.id = "SERIAL3" + index;
  cell3.appendChild(t3);
  
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var t4 = document.createElement("input");
  t4.id = "SERIAL4" + index;
  cell4.appendChild(t4);

  index++;
}
```

```html
<div id="popSerialList" title="Edit Engine Group">
  <B>Group Name:</B>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="GROUPNAME" size="50" />
  <table cellpadding="10" id="createTable">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="SERIAL1" onfocus="SerialAutoComplete(this)" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="SERIAL2" onfocus="SerialAutoComplete(this)" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="SERIAL3" onfocus="SerialAutoComplete(this)" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="SERIAL4" onfocus="SerialAutoComplete(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border:none;font-size:14px; padding:8px;">Add Users:</td>
      <td colspan="3" style="border:none; padding:8px;"><select id="addUsers1" name="addUsers1" style="width:300px;" multiple="multiple" style=font-size:14px;></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Add Row" name="AddRow" id="AddRow" class="button-green engineCancel" onClick="insertRow()" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

When I click on AddRow button, I am able to add my text boxes (4 in a row) but  I want to get my serial numbers onfocus on all the textboxes and not only for 4 text boxes, how can I make onfocus="SerialAutoComplete(this)" for all dynamic text boxes?

Comment: I had a question on this, how to put my code in comments? it says too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a loop to created the cells for each new row. Also, don't you want to add the new row *before* the button?

The following should add a new row after the last one and provide four columsn with text-input form elements.

Also, you can replace the `&nbsp;` characters with CSS margins.

```js
// Set the count to the current number of cells OR one.
var cellIndex = document.querySelectorAll('td>input[id^="SERIAL"]').length || 1;
var numOfCols = 4;

function insertRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById('createTable');
  var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length - 1);

  for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < numOfCols; colIndex++) {
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    var input = document.createElement('input');

    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.id = "SERIAL" + cellIndex;
    input.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
      return SerialAutoComplete(this);
    });
    cell.appendChild(input);
    
    cellIndex++;
  }
}

function SerialAutoComplete(self) {
  console.log(self);
}
```

```css
table tr:last-child td:nth-child(2) {
  border: none;
  padding: 8px;
}

.add-users {
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px;
}

#addUsers1 {
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#popSerialList>B,
#addUsers1 {
  margin-right: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div id="popSerialList" title="Edit Engine Group">
  <B>Group Name:</B> <input type="text" id="GROUPNAME" size="50" />
  <table cellpadding="10" id="createTable">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="SERIAL1" onfocus="SerialAutoComplete(this)" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="SERIAL2" onfocus="SerialAutoComplete(this)" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="SERIAL3" onfocus="SerialAutoComplete(this)" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="SERIAL4" onfocus="SerialAutoComplete(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="add-users">Add Users:</td>
      <td colspan="3">
        <select id="addUsers1" name="addUsers1" multiple="multiple"></select>
        <input type="button" value="Add Row" name="AddRow" id="AddRow" class="button-green engineCancel" onClick="insertRow()" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I want to add text boxes before the add row button, this is good but my serial autocomplete doesnt get called for all the dynamic textboxes, from frontend we are passing SERIAL1,2,3,4. how can I call onfocus for all the text boxes?

Comment: Sorry, I did not cover the listener. If you want to pass a self reference into the event function, you will have to wrap it and pass in your own parameters.

Comment: On edit, I should be able to see all the filled text boxes,  I am able to achieve that only when I click on Add Row button in edit popup, how can I load all the filled serial text boxes on click of Edit button.                                  
 I am unable to add my code here in comment section to show you, can you please help on how to put my code here?

Comment: When i alert my json data, it displays as [{"SERIALNO_LIST":"1250AD,1234504AB,1234504AC,1234504AF,1234504AF,1234504AC,1234504AB,1250AD","CDSID":"MARDREY,","GROUPNAME":111}], can I take the count of how many serial numbers have been added and add row accordingly?

Comment: Can you help me with  this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element.addEventListener(event, function)`

Comment: Can you give an example of this?

Comment: I think you should adapt the solution to your problem. It is good for you. Check out this link https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

Comment: your event would be focus and the function would be SerialAutocomplete